# Round off nearest Value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to round off the floating value into nearest whole number like if value is

```
2.4 = 2
```

If my value is

```
2.5 = 3
```

I use round(),floor(),and toFixed() But it did only up,down,equal numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by you "need a jQuery function which is equivalent"? jQuery is JavaScript. Can you tell us what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Simply need JavaScript's Math.round method:

```js
console.log(Math.round(2.4));

console.log(Math.round(2.5));
```

Comment: I need to use it on jquery within my function i was tried like $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   var h = Math.round(2.4);
    alert(h);
  });
}); It shows next integer

Comment: @JeyakumarKumar Are you sure ? :)